# じゃなく、じゃなくて、じゃなくては、ではなく、ではなくて、ではなくては

Tags: grammar, conjugations

Which of the above are acceptable in the following construction?

彼氏は料理だけ＿＿＿＿、家事も出来る。

What I am confused about is which of the constructions are grammatical and which are not? I have used じゃなくては in the past without correction, but when using the more formal form ではなく, it seems as though て form is not used at all, and is in fact wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your question and welcome to Japanese Language Stack Exchange! Please could you provide more detail over what you are confused about and evidence of your research effort? That way, other users can more fully answer the question in a way that is useful to both you and others.

Comment: What I am confused about is which of the constructions are grammatical and which are not? I have used じゃなくては in the past without correction, but when using the more formal form ではなく, it seems as though て form is not used at all, and is in fact wrong.

Comment: That context is important to include in your question, not only for you to get a detailed answer as possible (which addresses your specific understanding), but also to ensure your is actually a "good one" for the purposes of the Stack Exchange, and isn't closed (as it has been -- see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you're asking the community here to put time and effort into thinking about your question, it is at the very least courteous to put some time and into your question itself.

Comment: I understand and I appreciate the feedback. I thought the context would have been obvious and it was more courteous to be as concise as possible, but clearly I've just confused people in this instance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「彼氏{かれし}は料理{りょうり}だけ＿＿＿＿、家事{かじ}も出来{でき}る。」

The key words in this incomplete sentence are 「だけ」 and 「も」.

Almost only by seeing the two tiniest kana words, we know right away that we are dealing with a "**not only A but also B**" type of sentence pattern here.

> "My (partner) can not only cook but he can also do the household chores."

The phrases that can safely fit into that empty spot must be in the forms of:

では**なく** and では**なくて** less informally and

じゃ**なく** and じゃ**なくて** informally.

(For each pair, the 「て」 makes it one step more informal than without.)

Basically, no other phrases would fit in either grammatically or contextually.  Neither 「じゃなくて**は**」 nor 「ではなくて**は**」 would belong there.  There is simply no reason that the final 「は」 is needed.

「なくて**は**」 is most often used in negative conditional/hypothetical constructs such as:

「君がいなくて**は**生きていけない。」 ("I can't live without you.")

「日本に来たら京都に行かなくてはならない。」 ("If you come to Japan, you've got to go to Kyoto.")